# Repeating an Array in C

Tags: c

I was wondering how to repeat an array in C any number of times.

Let's say I have an array like: `int Array[4] = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Is there a simple way to get an array: `int Array2[8] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

by doing some operation on `Array[4]`?

Comment: `man memcpy` ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Show the code you have which does what you want but is not simple enough to your taste.

Comment: Describing the *actual* problem might lead to a solution *not* requiring this... See [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Just use a loop.

Comment: Well, you could just do it explicitly, you know with a loop, with code.

Comment: If you need indices higher than 3 to reference repeated values, just mod it: `array[index % 4]`

Comment: Copying is easy (memcpy), but unlike in very high level languages, in C you also get to decide where you want the copy to go, and you have several choices, most straightforward of which are static memory, automatic memory (stack) or malloc'd memory. That's a paradigm shift from very high-level and C. You can't just think in terms of objects -- you need to think about where you want them.

Comment: C is a low-level language, with basic operations to create and manipulate basic objects in memory. If you want to do something high-level like copying lists, you'll just have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a bad idea, which will hit you in the foot later, but maybe try

```
#define VALUES 1, 2, 3, 4

int a[] = { VALUES, VALUES, VALUES, VALUES };
```

Comment: Why would you recommend this to anyone?

Comment: I see it as a *possible* way to do the requested, not a recommendation. Won't upvote this, but also don't see a reason to downvote..

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: my intention is not a recommendation, just a possible kludge that may be what the OP is after.

Comment: I don't think this is so bad, necessarily, but I also don't think it's responsive to the question.  The OP says he wants to generate the longer array by performing an operation on the shorter one; this does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...to get an idea on how you can do it.

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
  array2[i]=array[i%4];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good way to repeat an array in C any number of times because your explanation is not a good one. The modulo operation returns integers from [0,REPEAT) so doing +1 you have integers in [1,REPEAT].
Here is the code:

```
#define N 5
#define REPEAT 2
int main(){
    int arr[N];
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
        arr[i] = (i % REPEAT) + 1;
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   2
>   1
>   2
>   1

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this might be to use a VLA, sized to whatever you require, and filled by using the modulus operator. Disadvantages include the inability to return such an array from a function, and silent failure when the VLA can't be allocated for some reason. Of course, VLA's were introduced in C99, and then made optional in C11. Though they are commonly available, you may opt for the next method.

Perhaps a more reliable approach uses a function that allocates space for the new array. If `malloc()` fails, a null pointer is returned, so it is the responsibility of the caller to check this. It is also the callers responsibility to `free` the allocation when through with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_arr(size_t, int *);
int * expand_array(size_t, int *, size_t);

int main(void)
{
    int input_arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    size_t input_arr_sz = sizeof input_arr / sizeof *input_arr;
    size_t new_arr_sz = 17;

    /* Method 1: VLA */
    int new_arr_1[new_arr_sz];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < new_arr_sz; i++) {
        new_arr_1[i] = input_arr[i % input_arr_sz];
    }

    print_arr(new_arr_sz, new_arr_1);

    /* Method 2: function with malloc() */
    int *new_arr_2 = expand_array(input_arr_sz, input_arr, new_arr_sz);

    if (new_arr_2) {
        print_arr(new_arr_sz, new_arr_2);
    }

    free(new_arr_2);

    return 0;
}

void print_arr(size_t sz, int *arr)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        printf("%3d", arr[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int * expand_array(size_t input_sz, int *arr, size_t output_sz)
{
    int *new_arr = malloc(sizeof *new_arr * output_sz);
    if (new_arr) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < output_sz; i++) {
            new_arr[i] = arr[i % input_sz];
        }
    }

    return new_arr;
}
```

Program output:

```
  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1
  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

So if I have an array: int Array[4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];

To repeat it I used two for loops as such:

```
int Array2[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
         Array2[i*4 + j] = Array[j];
    }
}
```

The i*4 + j made it so I could count past four in the assignment of Array2